# Javascript else condition not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do a basic javascript/jquery animation. Basically, a div that is hidden under normal view, should come into view when clicking a button.

The problem I have is in the condition (the `if else` statement).

Here is the code that I am using.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    animationClick('#animateThis', '#someElement', '#startHere');
});

function animationClick(element, secondElement, elementToBeClicked) {
    element = $(element);
    elementToBeClicked = $(elementToBeClicked);
    secondElement = $(secondElement);
    var state = 0;
    var containerWidth = $('#container').width();
    elementToBeClicked.on("click", function () {
        if(state == 0) {
            secondElement.animate({
                top: '27%',
            }, 500);
            element.animate({
                left: '0%',
            }, 500);
            elementToBeClicked.html("Hide");
            state = 1;
        } else {
            alert('hehehe');
        }
    })
};
```

So, basically, this is what happens. The whole function is put into document.ready. When I click on the button (which this function is bonded to),the `if` statement returns `true`, and the code gets executed. It also sets the state to `1`.

After the state gets set to `1`, the `else if` statement should come into action and show an `alert("hehehe")`, but it does not.

Can anyone give me some kind of an advice? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Function must be function

Comment: @Sushil What do you mean by that?

Comment: f of function should be in lowerCase

Comment: Oh - yeah it is 'f' in the original document. I pasted the whole function here, but the first letter got left off, so I accidentally made it a capital one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already bind a `"click"` event to `"elementToBeClicked"` at the first `if` statement.
Try to `unbind` it at the end of the `if` statement and then see what happens, but generally in order to only check that the `else` is executing, just put the alert out of the `click` event.

Comment: Fixed it. Still not working. There are no errors in the console. I notice that every click after the first one just executes the if statement one more time...

Comment: Ah - it's okay now. I had mixed up two versions of the script. However, your advice fixed my problem and helped me very much. I am very grateful to you!

Answer (score 1):

your variable "state" is local to the function.
That is why on subsequent calls of the function it is always 0.
initialize the variable outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when you compare variables and zero in if statement you should use  three ===. Like this : if (state === 0)